# iPad WordPress theme?

Tags: theme-development, themes

I want to convert one [HTML5/CSS3 theme](http://themeforest.net/item/vpad-html5css3-app-framework/885302?WT.ac=search_item&WT.seg_1=search_item&WT.z_author=vivantdesigns) in WP

This theme is build for iPads, now my question is is that possible to convert it?
If yes then how?
I mean should i create each different page template (ex. dashboard, calender etc..)

I just want to conform it before start that how should i need to understand before start it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definitely is possible, and you should really read the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page) before diving in, and read it in-depth. It's very well documented and usually a simple Google search will bring up answers for many of your questions.

The WordPress Codex will explain everything for you, especially [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Themes) for your situation, regarding creating a theme. Pay attention to the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) as well to be able to customize certain pages without much work.

The Codex also has a [Where to Start](http://codex.wordpress.org/New_To_WordPress_-_Where_to_Start) page that can be of tremendous use.

You can also check out other questions tagged with [`<theme-development>`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme-development) for many common questions that WP developers have.

All I can suggest is read, read, read!

**Edit:** [This page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) is also a good read to begin. :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Additionally, if it's purely iPad, you only need to cater to 2 static widths, makes it a whole lot easier in terms of media queries, image handling, etc.